# Reversing a LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity, reverse

So I need to reverse a Linked List in O(N) time/space.

This implementation is what I came up with using only the LinkedList class in the Java standard library (which doesn't give me access to the nodes themselves).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original code was on an external site (see edit history) and isn't available any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not.  `input.get(idx);` is itself `O(idx)` in time, which makes your implementation quadratic in time.

You will probably want to use an iterator (or better yet [`listIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator%28int%29)).

EDIT: Also, you could easily eliminate holdPopped with a little rearrangement.

`holdPopped.add` will be trivially O(1) in both time and space since you're pre-allocating space (which is O(n) in space) by passing the size.

IIRC, `holdLL.add` is amortized O(1) in time and space as well.  Sometimes it will be more, sometimes less, but the total space is n, so it should average to to O(n).  You can simplify the analysis by using `holdLL.ensureCapacity`.

Comment: ahhhhh I see, Thanks for catching that!

So I should ideally be using an iterator. I'll fix it, thanks again.

Comment: I updated my method and I added in the holdLL.ensureCapacity too(not shown in the updated pastebin link), I really didn't know about that method, it's pretty cool! 

I think it should be O(N) time/space now

Answer (score 4):

The "better way" you ask of can exploit the fact that the Java `LinkedList` class has methods

- `addFirst`
- `addLast`
- `removeFirst`
- `removeLast`

Each of these are O(1).

You can get O(n) time and space behavior in a few ways here.  One such way is:

```
LinkedList<E> b = new LinkedList<E>();
while (!a.isEmpty()) {
    b.addFirst(a.removeFirst());
}
a.addAll(b);
```

This does the reversal "in place" (that is, the variable `a` references the exact same object at all times).  It is equivalent to using a stack as temporary storage (`b` is the "stack").

It is O(n) time and O(n) space, despite the ugly copying.

Comment: Hey thanks alot! I changed it to take advantage of the O(1) methods. I needed to reverse it in place so I changed the algoritm a bit. I felt like the copying back and forth could be eliminated by keeping my implementation of a stack.

Comment: Shouldn't it be removeFirst and AddFirst to reverse the list, as removeLast and addFirst will simply copy the list (as those actions preserve the ordering)?

Comment: Thanks @Mark you are absolutely right!  I took the opportunity to clean up the answer and use real code.  I should have tested it when I gave the first answer #shameonme.

Answer (score 1):

The Java API has a method for this that completes in O(n): [`Collections.reverse(List<?> list)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29). Assuming this is homework you should implement this yourself, but in real life you would use the library function.

Alternatively, you can create a reverse decorator which makes the reversal O(1). An example of the concept is below.

```
public class ReversedLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {

  private final LinkedList<T> list;

  public ReversedLinkedList(LinkedList<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }

  public Iterator<T> descendingIterator() {
    return list.iterator();
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return list.descendingIterator();
  }

  public T get(int index) {
    int actualIndex = list.size() - index - 1;
    list.get(actualIndex);
  }

  // Etc.
}
```

Note that it is generally (always?) bad form to make a decorator extend a concrete class. Ideally you should implement the public interface and accept a constructor parameter as an instance of the public interface. The above example is purely for illustration purposes, as the LinkedList happens to implement a lot of interfaces (e.g. Dequeue, List etc).

Also, insert the typical "Premature optimisation is evil" comment here - you would only create this reversed dequeue class in real life if your list was actually a bottleneck.

Comment: Lines 412-435 of http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html if you want to see how the JDK implementors did it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check **apache commons**, they have better and more flexible implementations for the **linkedlist** and **collections** in general;

https://commons.apache.org

And secondly, it would be more easy for you to use a **doubly linked list** if you want to reverse a list.